# Disable all the <select> items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `<select>`s items in my JSP file, what I want is to disable all the `<select>`s items.

This is my JSP file:

```
<select id="comboSuperGrupos1" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos2" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
var combosSuperGrupo = document.getElementsByName("combosSupG");
combosSuperGrupo.disabled = true;
```

But I can't achieve my goal. I'm thinking to do that with jQuery, but I don't know if I can mix JavaScript with jQuery.

Any question post on comments.

Comment: You *have* to loop. There is no alternative. Even if you use jQuery, it's looping internally. You just don't see it

Comment: You can use vanilla javascript with jQuery. jQuery is really just a library made to make js developers lives easier.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const combosSuperGrupo = document.getElementsByName("combosSupG");
combosSuperGrupo.forEach(_ => _.disabled = true);
```

```html
<select id="comboSuperGrupos1" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos2" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? You probably want to use .querySelectorAll to chain an .forEach onto it

Comment: What is your complaint?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery :

```
$('select[name="combosSupG"]').attr('disabled',true);
```

JavaScript :

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[name='combosSupG']");
selects.forEach(function(s){
    s.disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes you can and it's easier to code:

This is how to disable every select with that name:

```js
$("select[name='combosSupG']").prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos1" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos2" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>
```

This is how to disable every select in the page:

```js
$("select").prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos1" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>

<select id="comboSuperGrupos2" name="combosSupG">
    <option value="0">N...</option>
    <!-- X OPTIONS -->
</select>
```